# Turn on/off GCP Compute Engine Instance via HTTP request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

How can I turn on/off (or perhaps check status of) a Google Compute Engine VM instance using an external HTTP request (for instance, via Slack)?

This is possible with AWS, there are even Slack integrations for AWS instances, but how about for Google Cloud Platform? I imagine this involves writing and deploying a Google Cloud Function, and there are startInstance/stopInstance functions in the GCP nodeJS samples [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js).

NOTE: This is not something for an automatic scheduler, and most documentation/articles about starting a VM uses Google Cloud Scheduler [a la this](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule#gcloud_1). However I'm not sure/don't think that Pub/Sub can be used in this setting with an external app like Slack.

Comment: Google provides SDKs for interfacing with the Compute Engine Management API. What is missing that you need to do? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1

Comment: Actually that was going to be a separate question. I had looked through that API reference but the documentation is not explicit for a beginner. Namely if I use https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start I am not sure about details of how to provide authorization credentials.

Comment: Use Google search: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Answer (score 1):

This post is not an answer yet. I'll edit this. I am writing here because I don't have enough reputation to add a comment. Sorry about this. :/

The mentioned Computed Engine Management API can't be a solution for this case since you can't use required authentication in an app like Slack. You need to authenticate with a key.

I think using Cloud Functions to start/stop instances (created by using the [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js) that's mentioned in the question) is an applicable way. But they are public endpoints by default, and we have to secure them. I found 2 ways to secure Cloud Function:

1. Implementing your authentication check in the function. Here is a solution: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js
2. Putting an endpoint in front of a Cloud Function to be able to restrict the access and authenticate with API Keys (which are specific to your project). https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions.

The second option looks better to me. We can secure a Cloud Function by using this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions). The only extra step is modifying the openapi-functions.yaml file in the tutorial (to enable API Key security). The content below does the job.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
  description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: [HOST]
schemes:
  - https
security: []
paths:
  /hello:
    post:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
      security:
        - api_key: []
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://[REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME]
        protocol: h2
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
# [START securityDef]
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
# [END securityDef]
```

I'll implement the whole system with Slack integration and update this post. Sorry again if this post annoys you since it's not a legit answer yet.